# How to parse xml data to display on web view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

i want intent my data from list view to webview. how to display xml parse on web view ?
this is my code intent from list view :

```
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);           
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Headline = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String ArticleDate = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date)).getText().toString();
            String Body = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.body)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in =new Intent ();
            in.setClass(news.this.getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            Log.i(KEY_HEADLINE, Headline);
            Log.i(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, ArticleDate);

                in.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, Headline);                
                in.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, ArticleDate);
                in.putExtra(KEY_BODY, Body);
            startActivity(in);

        } 
    });
```

Comment: do you want to use `headline` ,`ArticleDate` and `Body` in a web view?

Comment: Couldn't understand what you want!

Comment: yes. i want use headline, ArticleDate and Body in a webview @dmsherazi

Answer (score 0):

use this code , here The first three lines are to get the data u pass from the other activity. Then you would use these Strings to create a string in HTML format. The last line of code will show it in a webView. (Hope this helps)

```
String  Headline = getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_HEADLINE);
String  ArticleDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_ARTICLEDATE);
String  Body = getIntent().getExtras().getString(KEY_BODY);


 String html="<html><body><h1>"+Headline+"</h1><h4> Date:"+ArticleDate+"</hr><p>"+
            Body+"</p></body></html>"; // use HEadline ,Article date and body here
WebView webview = null;
webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```